# can import numpy module but cannot use functionalities

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

i had succesfully installed numpy (numpy-1.6.2-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe). But, whenever i try to call any functions i am getting following the error below. Thanks in advance for help.

```
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = np.arange(10)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arange'
```

Comment: If you fire up the python interpreter and type `dir(np)` what do you get?

Comment: .. you didn't happen to call any programs `numpy.py`, did you?

Comment: You could try printing `np.__file__` to make sure it's actually the system module and not an accidental script.

Answer (score 3):

Echoing one of the comments above (as I just had this problem, over 4 years later):

You probably named your file numpy.py. When trying to load a module, I believe the path checks the current directory first, and thus it isn't found.

For sanity, to check that it really is this issue, you should run the Python REPL (`python`) and type:

`import numpy as np`, followed by `dir(np)`

And you should see all of the actual functions as output.

Answer (score 1):

This might also happen because you probably named your program file numpy.py (i made the same mistake)

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
for x in dir(np):
    print x
```

this should list all methods etc of your import, that way you can see if arange() is available.

you could also try

```
from numpy import *
```

and then just try:

```
print arange(10)
```

Can't think of much else. Odd that the import does not produce an error if arange is not there.